# WRMSR on x86_64 64bit RCX register value is wrongly set

Tags: c, assembly, msr

I want to write to the PMC1 register, so I want to set RCX to 188.

The code I use to use WRMSR instruction is attached at the end. The problem is that I pass eax and ecx value (64bit) into the macro, **but the %rcx register is always set to eax value.**

```
#define RTXEN_WRITE_MSR(eax, ecx)     __asm__ __volatile__(\
                                "movq %0, %%rax\n\t"\
                                "xorq %%rdx, %%rdx\n\t"\
                                "xorq %%rcx, %%rcx\n\t"\
                                "movq %1, %%rcx\n\t"\
                                "wrmsr"\
                                :\
                                :"r" (eax), "r" (ecx)\
                                :\
                                )


uint64_t eax = 0x14f2e
uint64_t edx = 0x188

printk("eax:%#018lx, edx:%#018lx\n", eax, edx);
RTXEN_WRITE_MSR(eax, ecx);
```

**When the RTXEN_WRITE_MSR(eax, ecx) is executed, the kernel panic! 
The register information is as follows:**

```
(XEN) CPU:    1
(XEN) RIP:    e008:[<ffff82c4c02166b1>] setread_perf_counter+0x251/0x4c0
(XEN) RFLAGS: 0000000000010046   CONTEXT: hypervisor
(XEN) rax: 0000000000014f2e   rbx: ffff8308558f7718   **rcx: 0000000000014f2e**
(XEN) rdx: 0000000000000000   rsi: 000000000000000a   rdi: ffff82c4c0270640
(XEN) rbp: 0000000000000001   rsp: ffff83086bec7cd8   r8:  0000000000000004
(XEN) r9:  0000000000000004   r10: 0000000000000004   r11: 0000000000000400
(XEN) r12: 0000000000014f2e   r13: 0000000200000000   r14: ffff83086bec7dd8
(XEN) r15: 00000000000000fb   cr0: 000000008005003b   cr4: 00000000001426f0
(XEN) cr3: 000000008ce6a000   cr2: ffff880115ca32a0
(XEN) ds: 002b   es: 002b   fs: 0000   gs: 0000   ss: e010   cs: e008
```

Can anyone help me see what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You know you can have your compiler pass your arguments in the right registers straight away?

```
asm volatile (
    "wrmsr"
    :
    : "a" ((uint32_t)eax)
    , "c" ((uint32_t)ecx)
    , "d" ((uint32_t)0)
);
```

The typecast to `uint32_t` ensures that the compiler will use the 32-bit register variants (`eax`, `ecx`, `edx`).

You can find the constrain modifiers for the intel registers here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints

On a side note: if you are using registers in your asm then you need to tell the compiler that you are doing so. You need to put all registers that you use and the compiler doen't know about into the clobber registers list after the third colon.

Comment: Hi @Sergey L. Thank you for your advice. But I think my code just put the varaible to general register and then move the value from general register to %eax, %ecx, etc. I don't know why it does NOT work. BTW, since the register I use is in the dest. and source, I don't need to put them to clobber list, which will cause compiling error.

Comment: @MikeXu: But what if the compiler decides to put the variable "ecx" in the register rax, rcx or rdx? Then your logic does not work. I think you need to put, rax, rdx and rcx in the clobber list. IMHO SergeyL's solution is the cleanest.

Comment: Hi @AndreasH. Could you please give me a link? I followed the manual "http://www.mindfruit.co.uk/2012/11/intel-msr-performance-monitoring-basics.html". BTW, I also used the keyword __Volatile__, not sure why compiler will optimize it

Comment: Hi @AndreasH. BTW, I add %rax, %rcx, %rdx in the clobber list, it does not compile, reporting error: AREG cannot be found. Is it because I use the wrong name?

Comment: The compiler does not optimize. You have to see, that %1 in the assembly will be replaced with a register name (because you passed the "r" constraint). But you might be trashing this register before the move is executing (note the compiler does not know that you are modifying some registers in your assembly). Alternatively try passing ecx as "m" (i.e. memory reference)

Comment: @MikeXu: hmm, I dont know the specific format for the clobber list. IIRC it has a special notation (check esp. the register names). Are you sure you do it according to the manual?

Comment: @MikeXu: The point is, that you dont know which register the compiler chooses for %1. It could be rax, rdx or rcx, which you are actually modifying in your assembly. But this the compiler does not know, because it does not parse the assembly.

Comment: @MikeXu The reason your code is not working is in my side note. You did not tell the compiler that you are overwriting the contents of `ecx`, `rax` and `rdx`. SO it used those registers to hold something, you overwrote them and then screwed everything up. If you want to move your variables there in asm (which I do not recommend) then you have to put the registers you use into the clobber list `asm ( ".." : .. : .. : "eax", "ecx", "edx")`. Othersie the compiler won't know that it should avoid those.